# Como eu trato uma tabela em html como se fosse um formulário

Tags: javascript, python, django

Estou desenvolvendo em django uma aplicação para pesquisa processual e ela seria feita com base em planilhas excel. Eu achei na internet tutoriais para selecionar as linhas da tabela, entretanto, não sei como desenvolver um botão com uma função que envie as linhas selecionadas como listas em Python para realizar a busca.

o HTML esta bem simples e a função javascript copiei de um tutorial da internet:

```js
var tabela = document.getElementById("minhaTabela");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
    var linha = linhas[i];
  linha.addEventListener("click", function(){

        selLinha(this, true); 
    });
}


function selLinha(linha, multiplos){
    if(!multiplos){
    var linhas = linha.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
      var linha_ = linhas[i];
      linha_.classList.remove("selecionado");
    }
  }
  linha.classList.toggle("selecionado");
}


var btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("visualizarDados");

btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var selecionados = tabela.getElementsByClassName("selecionado");
  //Verificar se eestá selecionado
  if(selecionados.length < 1){
    alert("Selecione pelo menos uma linha");
    return false;
  }

  var dados = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < selecionados.length; i++){
    var selecionado = selecionados[i];
    selecionado = selecionado.getElementsByTagName("td");
    dados += "CNPJ: " + selecionado[0].innerHTML + " - RAZÃO SOCIAL: " + selecionado[1].innerHTML + " - NOME FANTASIA: " + selecionado[2].innerHTML + "\n";
  }

  alert(dados);
});
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/banco.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<button id="visualizarDados">Visualizar Dados</button>

<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="minhaTabela">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>CNPJ</th>
      <th>RazaoSocial</th>
      <th>NomeFantasia</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>00000000000</td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxx S/A</td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>yyyyyyyyyyyy S/A</td>
      <td>yyyyyyyyyyyyyy</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script  src="{% static 'js/banco.js' %}" async> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Só que ao invés de enviar o alerta na tela, gostaria de receber essas como se os itens selecionados na tabela fossem um formulário. Não sei se isso é possível, porém não entendo praticamente nada de Javascript e não consegui achar esse tipo de informação na internet.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se alguém um dia precisar fazer isso o mesmo que fiz, vou deixar minha solução aqui. Resolvi através de uma gambiarra em que alterei o valor do botão atribuindo a variável dados que tinha no javascript.

Para isso, primeiro atribui um name e um value ao botão e o inseri dentro de um form:

```
<form action="{% url 'banco_de_dados' %}" method="post" class="form" name="form" id="formElem">

<button formmethod="post" name="botao" type="submit" value="" id="visualizarDados">Visualizar Dados</button>

</form>
```

Depois, no documento js, inseri no final, abaixo de alert(dados) o seguinte comando:

```
document.form.botao.value = dados
```

Então, quando clicava no botão ele mandava como valor as informações das linhas selecionadas.

No views no django eu acessei as informações através do seguinte comando:

```
def banco_de_dados(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location4 = str(request.POST.get('botao'))
...
```

Ai depois foi só tratar os dados.

Repito, não sei se essa é a melhor solução, entretanto, foi  a que consegui encontrar e que é funcional, espero que ela  possa ser útil para alguém.